# How to create slug url in nuxtjs without folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

What i need is this:

1. [www.mysite.com/first-post](http://www.mysite.com/first-post)
2. [www.mysite.com/second-post](http://www.mysite.com/second-post)
3. [www.mysite.com/third-post](http://www.mysite.com/third-post)

dynamic urls and without "blog" before the urls.

Instead of this:

1. [www.mysite.com/blog/first-post](http://www.mysite.com/blog/first-post)
2. [www.mysite.com/blog/second-post](http://www.mysite.com/blog/second-post)
3. [www.mysite.com/blog/third-post](http://www.mysite.com/blog/third-post)

What structure folder or configuration i need to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont wanna setup anything, you can just create this:
pages/first-post.js insted of pages/blog/first-post.js

So the structure will be:

```
pages/
  first-post.js 
  second-post.js
  third-post.js
```

Edit: you can just put "_" in filename like: pages/_post.vue

Comment: So that the slug of the post should be in the url but without it being inside the blog folder, in this case inside the blog folder it would be _post there it would be site.com/blog/the-5-programming-myths, but I need it to be site.com/the-5-programming-myths for example

Comment: @gerSu if I understand it correctly, you just need to put `pages/_post.vue`